# Heap out of memory error in automated test using Serenity BDD

Tags: java, selenium, out-of-memory, heap-memory, serenity-bdd

To run my automated tests, I need to run a java application through the browser (a document signer). The solution I found was to use a firefox profile where the option to run the java application is already memorized. Since I am using Serenity BDD, I just passed the firefox profile path as a parameter in a serenity properties file.

[image: Document signer]

However, when I pass the firefox profile as a parameter, the test returns the out-of-memory exception. I took the heap dump to analyze, but I couldn't come up with any solutions.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedMap.forEach(ImmutableSortedMap.java:588)
    at com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableBiMap.forEach(SingletonImmutableBiMap.java:65)
```

So I tried to increase the values ​​of -Xms and -Xmx to 4096m and 8192m respectively, but now Serenity just can't instantiate the webdriver. The path to geckodriver is also found in the serenity properties file and is correct.

```
net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver (Unable to write to underlying appendable
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'D01266052', ip: '10.10.244.89', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: ProvideNewDriver). See below for more details.
    at es.indra.autotestes.automation_project.pages.efisco.LoginPage.navegarLoginEfisco(LoginPage.java:47)
    at es.indra.autotestes.automation_project.pages.efisco.LoginPage.realizarLogin(LoginPage.java:72)
    at es.indra.autotestes.automation_project.steps.efisco.common.CommonSteps.realizarLoginEfisco(CommonSteps.java:22)
    at es.indra.autotestes.automation_project.steps.efisco.icms.IsencaoIcmsDiversosSteps.receberPedidoDeIsencaoDeIcms(IsencaoIcmsDiversosSteps.java:11)
    at es.indra.autotestes.automation_project.features.isencao_icms.IsencaoIcmsDiversosRunner.testeAReceberIsencaoDeIcmsDiversos(IsencaoIcmsDiversosRunner.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Heres the Thread Stack I caught from the heap dump:

[image: Heap dump leak suspect]

```
Forwarding newSession on session null to remote
  at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>()V (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.Arrays.copyOf([CI)[C (Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(I)V (Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/AbstractStringBuilder; (Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer; (Unknown Source)
  at java.io.StringWriter.write(Ljava/lang/String;)V (Unknown Source)
  at java.io.StringWriter.append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/io/StringWriter; (Unknown Source)
  at java.io.StringWriter.append(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Ljava/lang/Appendable; (Unknown Source)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$new$1(Ljava/lang/Appendable;Ljava/lang/String;)V (JsonOutput.java:111)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$$Lambda$175.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V (Unknown Source)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$JsonObject.write(Ljava/lang/String;)V (JsonOutput.java:413)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.append(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/json/JsonOutput; (JsonOutput.java:284)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$new$3(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Integer;)V (JsonOutput.java:124)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$$Lambda$179.consume(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (Unknown Source)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;I)Lorg/openqa/selenium/json/JsonOutput; (JsonOutput.java:264)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$null$23(Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (JsonOutput.java:177)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$$Lambda$218.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSortedMap.forEach(Ljava/util/function/BiConsumer;)V (ImmutableSortedMap.java:588)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$new$24(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Integer;)V (JsonOutput.java:176)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$$Lambda$210.consume(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (Unknown Source)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;I)Lorg/openqa/selenium/json/JsonOutput; (JsonOutput.java:264)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$null$23(Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (JsonOutput.java:177)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$$Lambda$218.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.TreeMap.forEach(Ljava/util/function/BiConsumer;)V (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Ljava/util/function/BiConsumer;)V (Unknown Source)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$new$24(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Integer;)V (JsonOutput.java:176)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$$Lambda$210.consume(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (Unknown Source)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;I)Lorg/openqa/selenium/json/JsonOutput; (JsonOutput.java:264)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$null$23(Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (JsonOutput.java:177)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$$Lambda$218.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableBiMap.forEach(Ljava/util/function/BiConsumer;)V (SingletonImmutableBiMap.java:65)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.lambda$new$24(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Integer;)V (JsonOutput.java:176)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput$$Lambda$210.consume(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (Unknown Source)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;I)Lorg/openqa/selenium/json/JsonOutput; (JsonOutput.java:264)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/json/JsonOutput; (JsonOutput.java:255)
  at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toJson(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String; (Json.java:42)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(Ljava/util/Map;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/NewSessionPayload; (NewSessionPayload.java:100)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/NewSessionPayload; (NewSessionPayload.java:94)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/http/HttpClient;Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/Command;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/ProtocolHandshake$Result; (ProtocolHandshake.java:68)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/Command;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/Response; (HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/Command;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/Response; (DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/Response; (RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;)V (RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/CommandExecutor;Lorg/openqa/selenium/Capabilities;)V (RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(Lorg/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions;)V (FirefoxDriver.java:147)
  at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.FirefoxDriverProvider.lambda$newMarionetteDriver$0(Lorg/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions;Lnet/serenitybdd/core/webdriver/servicepools/DriverServicePool;Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver; (FirefoxDriverProvider.java:70)
  at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.FirefoxDriverProvider$$Lambda$153.newDriver(Lnet/serenitybdd/core/webdriver/servicepools/DriverServicePool;Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver; (Unknown Source)
  at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.ProvideNewDriver.withConfiguration(Lnet/thucydides/core/util/EnvironmentVariables;Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities;Lnet/serenitybdd/core/webdriver/servicepools/DriverServicePool;Lnet/serenitybdd/core/webdriver/driverproviders/InstantiateDriver;Lnet/serenitybdd/core/webdriver/driverproviders/InstantiateDriver;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver; (ProvideNewDriver.java:40)
  at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.FirefoxDriverProvider.newMarionetteDriver(Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities;Lnet/thucydides/core/util/EnvironmentVariables;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver; (FirefoxDriverProvider.java:66)
  at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.FirefoxDriverProvider.newInstance(Ljava/lang/String;Lnet/thucydides/core/util/EnvironmentVariables;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver; (FirefoxDriverProvider.java:52)
  at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.createWebDriver(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Lnet/thucydides/core/util/EnvironmentVariables;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver; (WebDriverFactory.java:169)
  at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.newWebdriverInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Lnet/thucydides/core/util/EnvironmentVariables;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver; (WebDriverFactory.java:150)
  at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newDriverInstance()Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver; (WebDriverFacade.java:141)
  at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newProxyDriver()Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver; (WebDriverFacade.java:132)
  at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.getProxiedDriver()Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver; (WebDriverFacade.java:102)
  at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.manage()Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver$Options; (WebDriverFacade.java:332)
  at es.indra.autotestes.automation_project.pages.efisco.LoginPage.navegarLoginEfisco(Ljava/lang/String;)V (LoginPage.java:47)
  at es.indra.autotestes.automation_project.pages.efisco.LoginPage.realizarLogin(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V (LoginPage.java:72)
  at es.indra.autotestes.automation_project.steps.efisco.common.CommonSteps.realizarLoginEfisco(Ljava/lang/String;)V (CommonSteps.java:22)
  at es.indra.autotestes.automation_project.steps.efisco.icms.IsencaoIcmsDiversosSteps$ByteBuddy$R9YJgPBv.realizarLoginEfisco$accessor$PjF9yMzU(Ljava/lang/String;)V (Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)Ljava/lang/Object; (StepInterceptor.java:471)
  at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.executeTestStepMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (StepInterceptor.java:451)
  at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runTestStep(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)Ljava/lang/Object; (StepInterceptor.java:424)
  at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runOrSkipMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)Ljava/lang/Object; (StepInterceptor.java:180)
  at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.testStepResult(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)Ljava/lang/Object; (StepInterceptor.java:167)
  at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.intercept(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)Ljava/lang/Object; (StepInterceptor.java:75)
  at es.indra.autotestes.automation_project.steps.efisco.icms.IsencaoIcmsDiversosSteps$ByteBuddy$R9YJgPBv.realizarLoginEfisco(Ljava/lang/String;)V (Unknown Source)
  at es.indra.autotestes.automation_project.steps.efisco.icms.IsencaoIcmsDiversosSteps.receberPedidoDeIsencaoDeIcms(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V (IsencaoIcmsDiversosSteps.java:11)
  at es.indra.autotestes.automation_project.steps.efisco.icms.IsencaoIcmsDiversosSteps$ByteBuddy$R9YJgPBv.receberPedidoDeIsencaoDeIcms$accessor$PjF9yMzU(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V (Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.invokeMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)Ljava/lang/Object; (StepInterceptor.java:471)
  at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.executeTestStepMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (StepInterceptor.java:451)
  at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runTestStep(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)Ljava/lang/Object; (StepInterceptor.java:424)
  at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.runOrSkipMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)Ljava/lang/Object; (StepInterceptor.java:180)
  at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.testStepResult(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)Ljava/lang/Object; (StepInterceptor.java:167)
  at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepInterceptor.intercept(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)Ljava/lang/Object; (StepInterceptor.java:75)
  at es.indra.autotestes.automation_project.steps.efisco.icms.IsencaoIcmsDiversosSteps$ByteBuddy$R9YJgPBv.receberPedidoDeIsencaoDeIcms(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V (Unknown Source)
  at es.indra.autotestes.automation_project.features.isencao_icms.IsencaoIcmsDiversosRunner.testeAReceberIsencaoDeIcmsDiversos()V (IsencaoIcmsDiversosRunner.java:32)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall()Ljava/lang/Object; (FrameworkMethod.java:50)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run()Ljava/lang/Object; (ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (FrameworkMethod.java:47)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate()V (InvokeMethod.java:17)
  at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityStatement.evaluate()V (SerenityStatement.java:33)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(Lorg/junit/runners/model/Statement;Lorg/junit/runner/Description;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V (ParentRunner.java:325)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(Lorg/junit/runners/model/FrameworkMethod;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V (BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
  at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner.performRunChild(Lorg/junit/runners/model/FrameworkMethod;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V (SerenityRunner.java:463)
  at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner.runChild(Lorg/junit/runners/model/FrameworkMethod;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V (SerenityRunner.java:438)
  at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner.runChild(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V (SerenityRunner.java:45)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run()V (ParentRunner.java:290)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V (ParentRunner.java:71)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V (ParentRunner.java:288)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(Lorg/junit/runners/ParentRunner;Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V (ParentRunner.java:58)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate()V (ParentRunner.java:268)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V (ParentRunner.java:363)
  at net.serenitybdd.junit.runners.SerenityRunner.run(Lorg/junit/runner/notification/RunNotifier;)V (SerenityRunner.java:242)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/runner/TestExecution;)V (JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run([Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/runner/ITestReference;)V (TestExecution.java:38)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/runner/TestExecution;)V (RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit/runner/TestExecution;)V (RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run()V (RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V (RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

All this could be avoided if I simply don't use the firefox profile, the test runs perfectly. However, I REALLY NEED the settings contained in that firefox profile. Can anyone help me with this? I'm dying inside.

Comment: Create a fresh profile and save only that option.   There are a lot of plugins that are not compatible with webdriver... I think it's any content which can't be easily serialized to json.

Comment: Yep, it worked. I don't believe it was that. Simply making a new profile without extensions and plugins solved the problem. Thank you, very much.

Answer (score 1):

Simply making a new profile without extensions and plugins solved the problem.